# unable to locate the text file

Tags: python

So I have the directory struture like this

```
  Execute_directory--> execute.py
  |
  Algorithm ---> algorithm.py
            |
            |--> data.txt
```

So I am inside execute directory and have included the following path to my python path.

```
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + "/../Algorithm")
```

algorithm.py has a code to read data.txt

So when I run execute.py , execute.py calls algorithm.py which in turns read data.txt
I thought that above line should have done the job. it is able to find algorithm.py but not data.txt??

```
         IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:'data.txt'
```

Any clue what I am doing wrong ??
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you reading `data.txt` in `algorithm.py` like this:

```
open('data.txt')
```

Because that is relative to the *working directory* and not relative to the scripts directory.

In `algorithm.py` you could try this:

```
open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'data.txt'))
```

Comment: yes. I am doing  f = open(filename,'r') what is the right way to read this file?

Answer (score 2):

This would usually be an issue with relative filenames not being relative to where you expect. Print the contents of `os.path.abspath(filename)` to check this. If it gives you something strange, specifying the absolute path in the first place (when you initialise `filename`) should fix it.

Comment: +1 this is excellent advice, as it teaches OP how to go about *solving* this problem next time it crops up as well as hints at how to solve similar problems too.

Answer (score 1):

`sys.path` is used to tell Python where to look for modules when you use `import`. It does not affect looking for files with `open`. When you open a file, relative paths are relative to the "current working directory", which you can check with `os.getcwd` and change with `os.chdir`.

Bonus: if you check the value of `sys.path` at startup, you will see that it includes `''`. This tells Python to also check the current working directory for modules (as well as the hard-coded absolute paths in `sys.path`, which is why, if you start a Python interpreter while "in" (using a command prompt) the folder that contains your module, you don't have to tell it where to look for your module.